# symbolic definition of bijection?

Tags: functions

As I understand it, bijection works if each element of the co-domain is mapped to by exactly one element of the domain.

Could I write it as $$f(X) = \{\forall y {\in} Y \;\exists! x {\in} X : f(x) = y\}$$

I have just started trying my hand at symbolic math and the two Wikipedia articles that I skimmed over on bijection didn't have a symbolic definition unfortunately. So is this correct or can be made clearer in some way?

Comment: Why are you writing $f(X)=$ and putting the condition in curly braces? Seems fine without the extra stuff.

Comment: Ah, you may be right. Am I wrong in showing f(X) as the range of a function being equal to the bijective condition? Or is it me being a little to specific where its detrimental?

Comment: It's not a matter of being specific. I just have no idea how to parse what you've written. As far as I can tell, what you've written in curly braces is not a set, it is curly braces around a condition. Setting a set (on the left side) equal to curly braces around a condition (on the right side) is meaningless to me. Or is there some kind of notational convention you're using I'm not aware of?

Comment: Do you perhaps mean to write $\{ y\in Y\mid \exists! x\in X: y=f(x)\}$? That's valid set-builder notation, and then the set equality is equivalent to $f$ being a bijection. (But that, such a statement would be unnecessarily opaque; it'd be easier to just write $\forall y\exists! x: y=f(x)$ and be done with it.)

Comment: I just came off of a semester of a probability course and I guess I just put everything in brackets now, haha. My bad, you give me to much credit, I'm just dumb.

Comment: $\{\text{blah blah} \}$ is not a set notation but $\{\text{Bwaah} \ | \ \text{Bwaah is blah blah}\} $ is. In the former notation, you cannot even tell what the objects of the set are but in the latter notation, the objects of the set are all the Bwaah's that satisfy "blah blah".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following your idea (brackets aside), *i.e.* playing with quantifiers only, I would escalate as follows:

1. "formal" definition of a *map* $f\colon X\to Y$: $$\forall x\in X,\exists ! y\in Y\mid y=f(x)$$
2. "formal" definition of a *injective map* $f\colon X\to Y$: $$\forall y\in f(X),\exists ! x\in X\mid y=f(x)$$
3. "formal" definition of a *surjective map* $f\colon X\to Y$: $$\forall y\in Y,\exists x\in X\mid y=f(x)$$
4. "formal" definition of a *bijective map* $f\colon X\to Y$: $$\forall y\in Y,\exists !x\in X\mid y=f(x)$$

As a bonus, if you compare 4 with 1, you'll see that the bijective map $f$ automatically defines another one $g\colon Y\to X$, such that $y=f(x)$ and $x=g(y)$, and hence $g(f(x))=x$ ($g$ is the inverse map of $f$).